# Will a metastable solid convert to it's more stable form upon heating to the transition temperature of the more stable form?

Tags: thermodynamics, solid-state-physics, material-science, phase-transition

Let's say a solid has a stable phase (A) that exists below some temperature, T, and  A transitions to another stable phase B above that temperature. If you take a solid sample of B and rapidly quench it such that it forms some metastable phase (A'), then upon heating past T will you see the following sequence:

A' -> A -> B

or

A' -> B 
?

In other words, does the stable phase, A, have to appear between the metastable phase A' and B?

Comment: It might, it might not. The kinetics of the phase transition are different than the thermodynamics.

Comment: So if you heat very slowly to the transition temperature, you should see A'-> A -> B, but if you go quickly it's possible to jsut see A' -> B?

Comment: Recall that ‘diamonds are forever’ yet metastable at room temperature. You can even heat them quite high in oxygen-free environments. All depends on nucleation rates.

Comment: I don’t quite understand: if you quickly cool the substance in the high-temperature phase B below the phase transition point, then *this phase (B)* will become metastable with decreasing temperature, where does any phase  A' have to do with it?